# OrmLite doesn't apply soft delete filter on joins

Tags: c#, ormlite-servicestack

I've added a `SqlExpressionSelectFilter` to use the [soft delete](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite#soft-deletes) functionality in ServiceStack OrmLite. However, It only seems to apply the filter to the base table specified in the `From<T>` and not any tables joined with `Join<TFrom, TOther>`. Both of my types implement the interface I'm using in my filter. Is this something that is supported?

**Filter:**

```
OrmLiteConfig.SqlExpressionSelectFilter = query =>
{
    if (query.ModelDef.ModelType.HasInterface(typeof(IHasRecordStatus)))
    {
        query.Where<IHasRecordStatus>(q => q.RecordStatus != RecordStatus.Deleted);
    }
};
```

**Interface:**

```
public interface IHasRecordStatus
{
    [Alias("RECORD_STATUS")]
    RecordStatus RecordStatus { get; set; }
}

[EnumAsInt]
public enum RecordStatus : byte
{
    Added = 1,
    Changed = 2,
    Deleted = 3
}
```

**POCOs:**

```
[Alias("ITEM_MASTER")]
public class ItemMaster : IHasRecordStatus
{
    [PrimaryKey]
    [Alias("ITEM_ID")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Alias("UPC_EAN")]
    public string Upc { get; set; }

    [Alias("RECORD_STATUS")]
    public RecordStatus RecordStatus { get; set; }
}

[Alias("VENDOR_ITEM")]
public class VendorItem : IHasRecordStatus
{
    [Alias("VI_ID")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Alias("ITEM_ID")]
    public int ItemId { get; set; }

    [Alias("V_ID")]
    public int VendorId { get; set; }

    [Alias("RECORD_STATUS")]
    public RecordStatus RecordStatus { get; set; }
}
```

**Query:**

```
var query = db.From<VendorItem>()
              .Join<VendorItem, ItemMaster>((vi, im) => vi.ItemId == im.Id)
              .Take(2);

var result = db.Select(query);
```

**Output SQL:**

```
SELECT TOP 2 "VENDOR_ITEM"."VI_ID" AS "Id", "VENDOR_ITEM"."ITEM_ID" AS "ItemId", "VENDOR_ITEM"."V_ID" AS "VendorId", "VENDOR_ITEM"."RECORD_STATUS" AS "RecordStatus" 
FROM "VENDOR_ITEM" INNER JOIN "ITEM_MASTER" ON ("VENDOR_ITEM"."ITEM_ID" = "ITEM_MASTER"."ITEM_ID")
WHERE ("VENDOR_ITEM"."RECORD_STATUS" <> @0)
```

In the SQL that is generated, I would have expected the where clause to also contain `(AND "ITEM_MASTER"."RECORD_STATUS" <> @1)`, but it only contains the filter for the VendorItem table specified in the from clause.

I also found it odd that I had to specify the alias on both the interface and on the classes that implement it for it to work. I tried it on the interface only and on the POCO only and neither worked until I specified both. Is this by design?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OrmLite only executes `SqlExpressionSelectFilter` on the from table and when you query using an interface OrmLite won’t be able to find the metadata for the concrete type which is why it needed to be specified on the interface.